# How to change ggplot legend so that `fill` is a square and `linetype` is a line?

Tags: r, ggplot2, legend

I have a simple plot:

```r
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, fill = "fill")) +
  geom_violin(aes(linetype = "pattern"), 
              key_glyph = draw_key_path)
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

How can I change the legend to show the `fill` as a square, but the `linetype` pattern as just a line instead of a square?

Comment: look for `guide_legend(override.aes = ...)`, such as https://aosmith.rbind.io/2020/07/09/ggplot2-override-aes/ (and [`?guide_legend`](https://ggplot2.tidyverse.org/reference/guide_legend.html)).

Comment: (but I think you mean to do away with the gray background in the legend shape boxes, is that right? not sure previous comment addresses that ...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way to do this natively. Here is a hacky solution by writing your own key drawing function in combination with `guide_legend(override.aes = list(...))`.

```r
library(ggplot2)
#> Warning: package 'ggplot2' was built under R version 4.1.1

my_key <- function(data, params, size) {
  if (all(is.na(data$fill))) {
    draw_key_path(data, params, size)
  } else {
    draw_key_polygon(data, params, size)
  }
}

ggplot(mtcars, aes(mpg, disp, fill = "fill")) +
  geom_violin(aes(linetype = "pattern"),
              key_glyph = my_key) +
  guides(linetype = guide_legend(override.aes = list(fill = NA)))
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2021-11-08 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v2.0.1)</sup>